# The impossible place value question

Tags: sequences-and-series

My teacher recently gave me this question - she said when I got bored you can do this, and then she literally took a piece of paper and wrote this.
" Prove that 'an an-1 an-2... a3 a2 a1' is divisible by 3, if and only if 'an an-1 an-2... a2 a1' is. 
E.g. -  123 is divisible by 3 only because 1+2+3 = 6 and 6 is divisible by 3."

Someone please help me solve this.

Comment: Supplement: Prove that an integer is divisible by 9 if and only if the sum of its digits in Base Ten is divisible by 9.

Answer (score 0):

When we write abc in decimal numbers , we really mean it is 100a+10b+c. Divide it by 3 and get a+b+c as remainder. If this remainder is divisible by three, the number itself shall have no remainder when divided by three.